# Creating a Custom Sinusoidal Wave Line with Dynamic Data Using HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css, user-interface, frontend, google-web-designer

**Description**:
I'm working on a project where I need to create a custom sinusoidal wave line using HTML and CSS. I have a reference image of the wave that I'd like to recreate, and I need this wave line to be able to display dynamic data.

[Sine Wave Line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/psUEi.png)
**Tags**: html, css, web-development

**Requirements**:

- I want to create a sinusoidal wave line similar to the reference image.
- The wave should be adaptable to display dynamic data points along its path.
- I need help with the HTML and CSS code to achieve this effect.

Comment: you need SVG too

Comment: You might want to use a JavaScript library for generating graphs. There are quite a few out there. I think D3 is used quite often.

Comment: Hi Himanshu, welcome to SO! People on SO are not going to write your code for you. Do the [tour] and show a [reprex]. In the mean time, here's a Codepen example showing how to draw a sinus: [SVG Paths - Lines, Curves, & CSS Transition V2,](https://codepen.io/mohammed-muzzy-sean-khan/pen/xxVqYxr) by *Mohammed Muzzy Sean Khan*.

Answer (score 0):

you can use from Chart.js. this work is easier

Comment: Thanks for the response @Mohammad. But how Chart.js will enable us to add custom buttons and actions?

Comment: you're welcome, this is Chart JS document: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/
you can read with this document, implementing to your button